# Media Player android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm struggling on designing a little audio player.

Just a list of 4 songs - each has it's own textView and when a user clicks on a textView a song starts playing but i have no idea how to make this. I though about making a onClick method for each textView but really dont like this idea.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    MediaPlayer varMediaPlayer;
    TextView song1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song1);
    TextView song2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song2);
    TextView song3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song3);
    TextView song4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song4);
   /* MediaPlayer hell = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Hell);
    MediaPlayer bells = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.HellsBells);
    MediaPlayer shoot = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Shoot);
    MediaPlayer thunder = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Thunderstruck);*/

   public void playMusic (View view) {
       
       varMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.Hell);
       varMediaPlayer.start();


   }




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the following variables:

```
TextView song1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song1);
TextView song2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song2);
TextView song3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song3);
TextView song4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song4);
```

will make your app crash as your assigning the variables when the `MainActivity` object is created.

move those to `onCreate(Bundle)` and assign a click listener to each of those `TextViews`

```
private static final int RAW_MUSIC_1 = R.raw.Hell;
private static final int RAW_MUSIC_2 = R.raw.HellsBells;
private static final int RAW_MUSIC_3 = R.raw.Shoot;
private static final int RAW_MUSIC_4 = R.raw.Thunderstruck;

private MediaPlayer varMediaPlayer;
private TextView song1, song2, song3, song4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // assign after setContentView(...) as findViewById scan the content view layout
    song1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song1);
    song2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song2);
    song3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song3);
    song4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song4);

    // add click listeners
    song1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            playMusic(RAW_MUSIC_1);
        }
    };
    song2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            playMusic(RAW_MUSIC_2);
        }
    };
    song3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            playMusic(RAW_MUSIC_3);
        }
    };
    song4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            playMusic(RAW_MUSIC_4);
        }
    };
}
```

and change `playMusic(View)` method to `playMusic(int)` and add `release` and `reset` methods to release object from memory

```
private void playMusic(final int musicId) {
    try {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mediaPlayer.reset();
    } catch (final Exception e) {}
    try {
        mediaPlayer.release();
    } catch (final Exception e) {}

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, id);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: many many thanks for such detailed explanation!

Comment: @irenavox i hope that helped you out (:

Answer (score -1):

```
Replace your code with this one and try running this...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer varMediaPlayer;


MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();



public void playMusic (Integer id) {

    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this , id);
    mediaPlayer.start();

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView song1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song1);
    TextView song2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song2);
    TextView song3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song3);
    TextView song4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song4);

    song1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playMusic(R.raw.hell);
        }
    });

    song1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playMusic(R.raw.HellsBells);
        }
    });

    song1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playMusic(R.raw.Shoot);
        }
    });

    song1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playMusic(R.raw.Thunderstruck);
        }
    });
}
```

}